Method showPopup is not supported in version 6.0
Не детектит telegram библиотеку с документацией, хотя source верный:
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web- 
app.js"</script>
<script>
var WebApp = window.Telegram.WebApp;
WebApp.showAlert(`Welcome, @${WebApp.WebAppUser}.`);
</script>

Ошибки:
Method showPopup is not supported in version 6.0
telegram-web-app.js:1784 Uncaught Error: WebAppMethodUnsupported
at WebApp.showPopup (telegram-web-app.js:1784:13)
at WebApp.showAlert (telegram-web-app.js:1883:12)
at index.html:59:12


"Не детектит telegram библиотеку с документацией" -- расшифруйте что там у Вас не детектит и при чем там документация. WebApp.showAlert() доступен начиная с версии Bot API 6.2, при чем там source вообще, в ошибке так и указано что данный метод не поддерживается для версии 6.0. Ну и теги <script> не мешало бы нормально открыть и закрыть.
